# Image inside a flex item with flex-direction:column increases the parent's height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm creating a layout that should take the full screen height and contain three parts:

- paragraph of one to several lines
- image
- bottom panel

The space remaining after the paragraph is layed out should be divided between image and bottom panel, with image taking 3x height of the panel.

I've started with a flexbox layout:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

            .Parent {
                height: 100vh;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .Parent > div {
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
                padding: 0.5rem;
            }

            .paragraph {
                background: pink;
            }

            .flex-smaller {
                flex: 1;
                background: lightblue;
            }

            .flex-bigger {
                flex: 3;
                background: lightgreen;
            }

            .flex-bigger img {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="Parent">
            <div class="paragraph">one paragraph</div>
            <div class="flex-bigger">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x800"/>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-smaller">
                Boudin filet mignon bacon short ribs shank beef ribs. Ground round landjaeger buffalo corned beef turkey tenderloin, beef ribs flank prosciutto doner
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And when there is no image, it looks correctly.  When the image is smaller than the available space, it stretches to 100% of the container height as expected.  However, if the image is *bigger* than the available space, it doesn't scale down: instead it increases the height of the container, and the whole page becomes higher than `100vh`.  How can I make the image scale down to fill the height of the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use overflow:hidden or min-height:0; to force height calculation and a reflow . so the container doesn't expand from its content over the room it is supposed to be . height:XX% then can be used

full explanation here : [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)

example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.Parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Parent>div {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.paragraph {
  background: pink;
}

.flex-smaller {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}

.flex-bigger {
  flex: 3;
  background: lightgreen;
/* reflow */
  min-height: 0; /* or  
  overflow:hidden; if not to be used otherwise */
}

.flex-bigger img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="paragraph">one paragraph</div>
  <div class="flex-bigger">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x800" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-smaller">
    Boudin filet mignon bacon short ribs shank beef ribs. Ground round landjaeger buffalo corned beef turkey tenderloin, beef ribs flank prosciutto doner
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If image has to be a mimimal height, overflow:auto can be used.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.Parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Parent>div {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.paragraph {
  background: pink;
}

.flex-smaller {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}

.flex-bigger {
  flex: 3;
  background: lightgreen;
/* reflow */
   
  overflow:auto;
 
}

.flex-bigger img {
  height: 100%;
  min-height:400px; /* demo purpose */
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="paragraph">one paragraph</div>
  <div class="flex-bigger">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" /> I'll be scrolling this time 
  </div>
  <div class="flex-smaller">
    Boudin filet mignon bacon short ribs shank beef ribs. Ground round landjaeger buffalo corned beef turkey tenderloin, beef ribs flank prosciutto doner
  </div>
</div>
```